# ModelSerializer required field data from instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have following serializer:

```
class TrackGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TrackGroup
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'report', 'tracks')  # `report` is FK
```

I am taking report id from url, so I thougth that this will work:

```
...
track_group = TrackGroup(report=report)
serializer = TrackGroupSerializer(
    instance=track_group,
    context=dict(request=request),
    data=request.data
)

if serializer.is_valid():
    ...
```

This doesn't work because serializer has error for field `report` as the field is missing and is required. What is a correct way to provide data like `report` and have it still listed in `TrackGroupSerializer` fields as this serializer is used to return all data in response.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution seems to be `partial=True`:

```
serializer = TrackGroupSerializer(
    instance=track_group,
    context=dict(request=request),
    data=request.data,
    partial=True
)
```

It seems to be cleaner than modifying request data.

Answer (score 1):

Set the required flag to **False** in model serializer

```
class TrackGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    report = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = TrackGroup
        fields = ('report', ...)
```

In case you want to create a serializer and save a model instance without providing value to a variable, you can always set a default value to it in the model.

In models.py

```
class TrackGroup(models.Model):
    report  = models.CharField(default = '-')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set data as a dict with all keys not as request.data like so

```
data = {'report': report.id, **request.data}

serializer = TrackGroupSerializer(
    instance=track_group,
    context=dict(request=request),
    data=data
)
```